# DeviceCapabilities generates error: data is invalid

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, print-spooler-api

I want to get a printer's list of paper source, paper size, etc.
I slightly modified the codes from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/DeviceCapabilities.html?diff=y
The codes sometimes work, sometimes not.
The proplem is DeviceCapabilities(DeviceName, strPort, DeviceCapabilitiesFlags.DC_BINNAMES, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)null) returns -1. the last error is "data is invalid"
Restart computer may not solve the problem. Once getting the problem, next time maybe OK maybe not.

So what is the problem here?

```
ArrayList arrBinName;
string sError = "";
GetBins("\\Lindy-PC.MyCpmpany.local\HP LaserJet 4000 Series PCL 5", "LPT1", out arrBinName, out sError);

    public static bool GetBins(string DeviceName, string strPort, out ArrayList BinName, out string strError)
    {
        strError = "";
        BinName = new ArrayList();

        IntPtr pAddr = default(IntPtr);
        int offset = 0;

        int nRes = DeviceCapabilities(DeviceName, strPort, DeviceCapabilitiesFlags.DC_BINNAMES, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)null);  //Returns -1
        if (nRes >= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                pAddr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)nRes * 24);
                nRes = DeviceCapabilities(DeviceName, strPort, DeviceCapabilitiesFlags.DC_BINNAMES, pAddr, (IntPtr)null);
                if (nRes < 0)
                {
                    strError = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message + "[" + DeviceName + ": " + strPort + ".DC_BINNAMES]";
                    return false;
                }

                offset = pAddr.ToInt32();
                for (int i = 0; i < nRes; i++)
                {
                    BinName.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new IntPtr(offset + i * 24)));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pAddr);
            }
        }
        else
            strError = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message + "[" + DeviceName + ": " + strPort + ".DC_BINNAMES]";

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If my memory serves me correct you call DeviceCapabilities twice. First to get paper settings int nPaperCount = DeviceCapabilities(sPrintName, "LPT1",  DC_PAPERS, NULL, DeviceMode); then again to get paper types DeviceCapabilities(sPrintName, "LPT1",  DC_PAPERS, moPT, &DeviceMode);

Answer (score 1):

As aggaton mentioned in his or her comment, `DeviceCapabilities` requires two calls in certain circumstances and retrieving bin names is one of them. You should first read the documentation for [DeviceCapabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Then go back and look at the sample code you used. You omitted a key step:

```
// BinNames
nRes = DeviceCapabilities(strDeviceName, strPort, DeviceCapabilitiesFlags.DC_BINNAMES, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)null);
pAddr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)nRes * 24);
nRes = DeviceCapabilities(strDeviceName, strPort, DeviceCapabilitiesFlags.DC_BINNAMES, pAddr, (IntPtr)null);
if(nRes < 0)
{
    strError = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message + "["+ strDeviceName +": "+ strPort +"]";
    return false;
}
```

Notice that there are **three** calls to `DeviceCapabilities` in that code. You need all three. (I think the code would be clearer by making each call a separate line of code but that's a style issue.) The doc for `DeviceCapabilities` plus the sample code above should get you back on track.